# Допустимо ли использовать функции в *.py файлах конфигурации?

Tags: python, best-practice

Иногда вместо того, чтобы пилить кучу фич в программе и кучу конфигов к этим фичам, хочется просто разрешить конечному пользователю писать кастомные простенькие функции в конфиге и писать в них простенькую логику, что-нибудь например вроде такого (придумано от балды):

```
# settings.py

def filter_for_processing(obj):
    return (
        obj.name.endswith('- Cool') or
        obj.author != 'admin' or
        (obj.type == 'circle' and abs(8 - 2 * math.pi * obj.radius) < 0.01)
    )
```

Только вот я такого в существующих проектах что-то не встречал. Максимум вот это в gettext:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && "
"n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2)\n"
```

Так вот: так делать хорошо или плохо? Слепой ли я, или проектов, в которых пихать функции в конфиги это норма, действительно нет? Или подобные даже примитивные вещи следует оформлять как плагины из одной функции и прописывать подключение плагина в конфиге?

Comment: Лучше сразу оформляйте в форме плагинов, ибо всегда найдется тот, кто будет жаловаться, что-де не хватает функционала для создания моей маленькой грандиозной функции! И вам и пользователям будет только профит! https://habrahabr.ru/post/281332/

Comment: Слишком обширный вопрос: это и хорошо и плохо, это и допустимо и не допустимо—всё зависит от конкретного приложения. Кстати, с высоты этого вопроса, разницы между плагинами и *«*.py файлами конфигурации» нет—и то и другое это способ выполнить код пользователя в контексте приложения. Emacs является примером, где код для конфигурации широко используется. Естественно лучше разрешать только те возможности, которые необходимы ([держитесь левой стороны на диаграмме](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch08s01.html)), но если уж разрешили код, то явно API проектируйте—не отставляйте на шанс